# Will cause memory leak?

Tags: c

Considering this "**pseudo-code**" sequence:

```
variable x

malloc(x);
free(x);
malloc(x);
free(x)
//..so on
```

Doing `malloc`, `free` sequence will cause memory leak? `realloc` is needed to be used instead?

Comment: Wait, you're _not_ using the result of _malloc_?

Comment: people... I am using pseudo-code.. just to illustrate the idea

Comment: I don't understand why you did not just loop it, run it overnight and see what happened.

Comment: What kind of application are you considering?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What might *perhaps* happen if you do allocation and deallocation in random order a zillions times in a long running process is [memory fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29). In practice it probably would happen only in a process running several *days*.

<sup>If you `malloc` a zone and `free` the *same* zone before any other allocation, fragmentation is less likely to happen. It would happen more likely with allocation and deallocation in some "random" order.</sup>

There is not much to do about that (notably if your application is `malloc`-ing zones of widely different sizes); you might use some compacting [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) algorithm (or something inspired by that, read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/)). You could also perhaps think in terms of [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), i.e. design your application with the ability to write and reload all its space on disk. Then after a few hours of work, you would checkpoint the state on disk, and restart the application from that state.

BTW, for long running applications you want to checkpoint for other reasons (e.g. avoid losing days of computation from a power failure).

You might think of upgrading your application between checkpoint and restart. This is tricky. Read about [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating) and about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

You could also use some higher level language implementation: [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) and [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) have compacting garbage collectors, so fragmentation is much less likely to happen when you code in these languages. And *Ocaml* has builtin [marshalling](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Marshal.html), and SBCL is able to save its state to disk using [`save-lisp-and-die`](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Saving-a-Core-Image)

On Linux, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a useful tool for debugging `malloc` related bugs.

PS. If you consider coding a long-lasting program running many days, you should think carefully at the design stage. IMHO embedding an interpreter (e.g. [GNU guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile)) is often worthwhile.

Comment: that was very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Doing several `free(malloc(n));` doesn't result in memory leak.
But it may fragment the memory.

Answer (score 1):

No, this should not cause a memory leak. `realloc()` is used to reallocate immediately instead of using `free()` first.

Comment: he doesn't use realloc at all, and never saves the result of malloc. furthere more, he uses junk data stored in `x`. it will probably crash

Answer (score 0):

You're using `malloc` incorrectly. You should do

```
char *data=malloc(24 * sizeof(char)); // or anything instead of 24
```

After you've allocated space you're free to `free` it and then allocate it again. It won't cause any leaks.

Comment: Try it once with compiler warnings enabled .It would  be a compilation error .

Comment: That's why I said enable your compiler warnings .

Comment: @ForceBru gcc says that `sizeof(void)` is invalid. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/owMFxCww2g6n3ICS

Comment: @MikeCAT, really? Didn't know about this, gonna edit my answer.

Comment: I am using **pseudo-code** to illustrate the idea. But thanks for the reminder. @ForceBru

Comment: @ForceBru Reason is `sizeof` cant be applied to incomplete type and `void` is incomplete type .

Answer (score 0):

no while you respect that each `malloc` should have its `free`. but, the code you provided it suspicious.

```
variable x

malloc(x);
free(x);
malloc(x);
free(x)
//..so on
```

it should be:

```
variable x

x=malloc(n);
free(x);

x=malloc(n);
free(x)

//..so on
```